# Cant access photo/muxic files through phone application

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

There was .nomedia file in my mobile. I removed the same but still I am not able to access my photos, music files through Gallery & music application. I am able to access the same through desktop using USB connection. Pls help...

Comment: Are you sure you have removed all .nomedia files that may cause this problem? You can do a file search using an app like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.in.zextr.sff And delete the related files. Also, have you tried rebooting after deleting .nomedia files?

Comment: Hi Suraj, are you talking about formatting the mobile?? I have re-started mobile various times but problem still persist. Can you please let me know how to reboot. I am using HTC One V.

Comment: Rebooting is same as restarting. As I said, are you sure you have deleted ALL .nomedia files? Check folder, parent folders and subfolders. Try searching ".nomedia" using any file search utility like mentioned earlier. If you have deleted all .nomedia files, try renaming the media folder.

Comment: I dont know y but its not working  :'(

Comment: Have you tried *all* the things I mentioned?

Comment: Yes...I have tried everything. Also when I am rebooting, my phone doesn't detect my SIM card. I have to use my SIM card in other mobile phone & then after inserting it again in my phone it starts detecting the SIM but problem of non-availability of photos/songs through mobile app remains. I have notices that these .nomedia files again coming into my phone after 2-3 days. Mostly in Whatapp & Dropbox folder.

Comment: I also removed the SD card but still not bale to access the music, photos, ringtones from internal memory. pls help :(